# PHPmyadmin Issue - Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mb_detect_encoding()

Tags: phpmyadmin

I keep getting this issue when I try to run Phpmyadmin from my localhost.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mb_detect_encoding() 
in C:\Apache24\htdocs\phpmyadmin\libraries\php-gettext\gettext.inc:177 Stack 
trace: #0 C:\Apache24\htdocs\phpmyadmin\libraries\php-
gettext\gettext.inc(282): _en code('The %s extensio...') #1 
C:\Apache24\htdocs\phpmyadmin\libraries\php-gettext\gettext.inc(289): _
gettext('The %s extensio...') #2 
C:\Apache24\htdocs\phpmyadmin\libraries\core.lib.php(306): __('The %s 
extensio...') #3 C:\Apache24\htdocs\phpmyadmin\libraries\core.lib.php(961): 
PMA_warnMissingExtension('mbstring', true) #4 
C:\Apache24\htdocs\phpmyadmin\libraries\common.inc.php(102): 
PMA_checkExtensions() #5 C:\Apache24\htdocs\phpmyadmin\index.php(13): 
require_once('C:\\Apache24\\htd...') #6 {main} thrown in 
C:\Apache24\htdocs\phpmyadmin\libraries\php-gettext\gettext.inc on line 177
```

I have repeatedly gone through and tried all of the suggestions that I can find regarding this issue and have yet to figure it out. I have tried various "/" "\" suggestions with no luck.

**Here are my httpd.conf settings:**

```
ServerRoot "c:/Apache24"


 </IfModule>
 LoadModule php7_module "c:/php/php7apache2_4.dll"
 AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
 PHPIniDir "c:\PHP"
```

**Here are my php.ini settings:**

```
 ; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
 ; http://php.net/extension-dir
   extension_dir = "C:/PHP/ext"
 ; On windows:
   extension_dir = "C:/PHP/ext"   



 ;extension=php_bz2.dll
 ;extension=php_curl.dll
 ;extension=php_fileinfo.dll
 ;extension=php_ftp.dll
  extension=php_gd2.dll
  extension=php_gettext.dll
 ;extension=php_gmp.dll
 ;extension=php_intl.dll
 ;extension=php_imap.dll
 ;extension=php_interbase.dll
 ;extension=php_ldap.dll
  extension=php_mbstring.dll
  extension=php_exif.dll      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
  extension=php_mysqli.dll
 ;extension=php_oci8_12c.dll  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
 ;extension=php_openssl.dll
 ;extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
 ;extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
 ;extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
 ;extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
 ;extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
 ;extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
 ;extension=php_pgsql.dll
 ;extension=php_shmop.dll
```

**PhpInfo**

```
 PHP Version 7.0.13
 System Windows NT SERVER 6.3 build 9600 (Windows Server 2012 R2    
 Standard Edition) AMD64
 Build Date Nov 8 2016 13:28:54
 Compiler   MSVC14 (Visual C++ 2015)
 Architecture   x64
 Configure Command  cscript /nologo configure.js "--enable-snapshot-build"      
 "--enable-debug-pack" "--with-pdo-oci=c:\php-  
 sdk\oracle\x64\instantclient_12_1\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8-12c=c:\php-
 sdk\oracle\x64\instantclient_12_1\sdk,shared" "--enable-object-out-
 dir=../obj/" "--enable-com-dotnet=shared" "--with-mcrypt=static" "-- 
 without-analyzer" "--with-pgo"
 Server API Apache 2.0 Handler
 Virtual Directory Support  enabled
 Configuration File (php.ini) Path  C:\Windows
 Loaded Configuration File  (none)
 Scan this dir for additional .ini files    (none)
 Additional .ini files parsed   (none)
 PHP API    20151012
 PHP Extension  20151012
 Zend Extension 320151012
 Zend Extension Build   API320151012,TS,VC14
 PHP Extension Build    API20151012,TS,VC14
 Debug Build    no
 Thread Safety  enabled
 Zend Signal Handling   disabled
 Zend Memory Manager    enabled
 Zend Multibyte Support disabled
 IPv6 Support   enabled
 DTrace Support disabled
 Registered PHP Streams php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, zip,      
 compress.zlib, phar
 Registered Stream Socket Transports    tcp, udp
 Registered Stream Filters  convert.iconv.*, mcrypt.*, mdecrypt.*,   
 string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags, convert.*,  
 consumed, dechunk, zlib.*
```

**Software/Hardware**

```
 - Windows Server 2016R2
 - PHP 7.0.13
 - Phpmyadmin (C:\Apache24\htdocs\phpmyadmin)
 - Apache 2.4
 - MySQL 5.7.1
```

I appreciate any help you can give me. Not sure what steps to take.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue on Windows 10 with Bitnami WAMP Stack version 7.0.12-0 (not sure if you are using Bitnami or some other WAMP stack, or none). I gave up troubleshooting (have you tried running the commands:

```
cd \php
deplister ext\php_mbstring.dll
```

In a Command Prompt, to check dependencies for PHP_MBSTRING.DLL, and see if you get any "NOTFOUND" errors?), and just installed the latest version of Bitnami, 7.0.13-1, and then phpMyAdmin worked immediately. (I had changed my httpd.conf and php.ini slightly in the previous version of Bitnami, so I may have broken phpMyAdmin with those changes).

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue 
i just update full extension folder path like this in php.ini file

```
extension_dir = "C:/wamp/bin/php/php7.1.13/ext/"
```

and updated latest phpmyadmin version
because phpmyadmin4.1.14 is not compatible with php7.
i wish it will resolve your problem